# How to escape curly braces and backslashes in YAML with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

My app validates and imports data files for various vendors. One of the validations on the file will be to check whether it's filename is in the right format. I have my regex stored in my YAML file along with various other configurations as follows -

```
---
filename_regex: !ruby/regexp '/^input_.{1,10}_company_\d{8}.tsv$/'
check_header_row: true
foo: "Bar"
....
```

Essentially the above enforces that it has to be of format: `input_companyName_company_20141127.tst`. I'm loading the file with `YAML.load(filename)` in the app.

I'm running into 2 problems, as you may have already guessed

1. The curly braces don't escape correctly. When I take them out it works fine, so those are almost certainly the problem. Apparently `\` doesn't work for escaping, and neither does `'` ?
2. The `\d` needs to have it's own backslash escaped, I assume? In that case would I use `\\d` in the file? That didn't seem to work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried building your data in Ruby and then calling `to_yaml` on it?

Comment: These are configuration files so I'd like all the data to live in YML configuration until I choose to load it. The specific implementation of my app is probably outside the scope of the question, so I'd be more curious on how to implement it this specific way. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't matter what they are. It is a YAML representation of a Ruby Hash so open up `irb`, write the Hash you're looking for, then call `to_yaml` on it to see what Ruby thinks the YAML should look like. For example, given `o = { 'filename_regex' => /^input_.{1,10}_company_\d{8}.tsv$/ }` then `o.to_yaml` says `filename_regex: !ruby/regexp /^input_.{1,10}_company_\d{8}.tsv$/`. PS: `^` and `$` are beginning and ending of *line* in Ruby, not *string*; you almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead. You could also check the [YAML specs](http://yaml.org).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate any problem with what you already have.

Don't forget you probably want to be escaping the `.` at the end for `.tsv` and as someone already mentioned use `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$` like `'/\Ainput_.{1,10}_company_\d{8}\.tsv\Z/'`

*regex.yml*

```
---
filename_regex: !ruby/regexp '/^input_.{1,10}_company_\d{8}.tsv$/'
foo: 'bar'
---
```

*regex.rb*

```
require 'yaml'

cfg = YAML.load_file('regex.yml')

valid_test_name = 'input_ABCD_company_12345678.tsv'
invalid_company_test_name = 'input_CompanyTooLong_company_12345678.tsv'
invalid_date_test_name = 'input_Company_company_12345678901.tsv'

valid_pass = valid_test_name =~ cfg["filename_regex"] ? 'pass' : 'fail'
invalid_company_pass = invalid_date_test_name =~ cfg["filename_regex"] ? 'pass' : 'fail'
invalid_date_pass = invalid_date_test_name =~ cfg["filename_regex"] ? 'pass' : 'fail'

puts "#{valid_test_name}: #{valid_pass}"
puts "#{invalid_company_test_name}: #{invalid_company_pass}"
puts "#{invalid_date_test_name}: #{invalid_date_pass}"
```

Running it `ruby regex.rb` outputs

```
input_ABCD_company_12345678.tsv: pass
input_CompanyTooLong_company_12345678.tsv: fail
input_Company_company_12345678901.tsv: fail
```